# How to keep a property file in some local memory once read by your rest microservice api

Tags: rest, microservices

I was in an interview and the interviewer asked me that a property file is present on the disk or github or where ever you like. Your rest api should read it from there. Api should read the file from the designated location only once and since then it should be stored some where in local memory. So subsequent requests made to the api should return the required properties in the property file from that local memory and not where the file is saved.How will you do it ?

I answered that we should use a local cache like eh cache. But he said no nothing like cache or db , it should be somewhere in local memory.

Comment: So, read it, parse and store in memory. It's not clear what exactly your question is about.

Comment: Correct, but those are the words directly from the interviewer .... maybe he meant to create a singleton bean and keep the file loaded in local variable of class ... but i am not sure though.

Comment: Then you probably should have asked them what exactly they mean?